# How to change canvas color in kivy python dynamicly?

Tags: python, canvas, colors, kivy

The aim is to change color of pen in kivy when user press button.The color will changed to button's background color.Code of the canvas:

```
def on_touch_move(self,color,touch):
    with self.pc.canvas:
        global wtd,pencolor
        Color(pencolor)
        if wtd == 1:
            Ellipse(pos=(touch.x,touch.y),size=(penrad,penrad))
```

Code of the on_press binded to button:

```
def newclr(self,instance):
    global pencolor
    pencolor = instance.background_color
    self.on_touch_move
    return pencolor
```

Buttons events works normally!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Solution

Provide the *mode* (rgb, rgba) of the Color. Replace ***Color(pencolor)*** with ***Color(rgba=pencolor)***

Please refer to the demo below for details. The pen colour started off as red and changed to white i.e. the background colour of the button.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.graphics import *


class MyWidget(Widget):
    wtd = NumericProperty(1)
    penrad = NumericProperty(10)
    pencolor = ListProperty([1, 0, 0, 1])  # Red

    def newclr(self, instance):
        print("Before Change@newclr: pencolor=", self.pencolor)
        self.pencolor = instance.background_color
        print("After Change@newclr: pencolor=", self.pencolor)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        print("on_touch_move: touch=", touch)
        print("on_touch_move: pencolor=", self.pencolor)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(rgba=self.pencolor)
            if self.wtd == 1:
                Ellipse(pos=(touch.x, touch.y), size=(self.penrad, self.penrad))


class TestApp(App):
    title = "Kivy - Change Pen Colour"

    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<CustomButton>:

<MyWidget>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 0, 1, 1    # Blue
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    Button:
        text: "Change Pen Color"
        size: 150, 100
        size_hint: None, None
        on_press: root.newclr(self)
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - App Startup]
[image: Img02 - Red Pen]
[image: Img03 - White Pen After Clicked Button]